# What is the point of import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common'; if I can already access the document

Tags: angular, dom, angular6, document, angular-module

Why should we bother using `import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common'`?

Even without it I can access the document module

```
document.getElementById('TestID).focus()
```

The only difference I see with the import is having it attached to `this` keyword.

```
this._document.getElementById('TestID').focus();
```

Is there any real benefit to importing DOCUMENT from Angular's common module?

I did some research but cannot see any information on this.

Comment: I guess the benefit is that it's easier to mock / stub, and therefore easier to test

Comment: This might be applicable for ServerSide rendering where you don't have a DOM and thus no `document`. I'm not really sure though.

Comment: Yea there doesn't seem to be much information on this. You can always mock the regular dom or add elements

Answer (score 19):

In our use case, the most important reason we inject the `DOCUMENT` instead of using it directly is for **Server Side Rendering**. If you call `document.xxx` directly in any regular lifecycle hooks like `ngOnInit`/`ngAfterViewInit`, you will mostly probably get `document not defined` error during *SSR*. Using DI to inject it could avoid this.

Comment: So you should be able to call methods like `getElementById` off of DOCUMENT in a server context?

Answer (score 4):

`DOCUMENT` can be unavailable in for example Web Worker. You can for example inject it optionally with

```
@Optional() @Inject(DOCUMENT) document
```

check if it's `undefined` and branch your code.

But then again you could probably just check `window.document` instead.

Comment: That is interesting to know however does not quite explain whats the use of importing DOCUMENT from angular when we can just use standard `document`. As well as if it has another benefits over using the standard `document`. Thanks for your help by the way

Answer (score 2):

How I understand this is that DOCUMENT represents the main rendering context , you can access document no matter what the platform is "Browser" or "Server".

From document.getElementByID, you can only access DOM Document.

Please refer to "[Angular Document](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DOCUMENT)".

Comment: So you think it has additional capabilities compared to the regular document object? 'represents the main rendering contex'. I am a bit confused what that this is exactly.